# Are there alternatives to the 'who.is' website?

Tags: linux, whois

I'm looking for alternatives to who.is. I tried the following Linux commands:

- `host -a`
- `dig example.nl ANY`
- `nslookup example.nl -all`

But none display all the information, just as in who.is website, DNS records and all.

I would love a all-in-one Linux command, that does what who.is does. But, a website is also accepted.

For me, searching for `.com` works fine, with `.nl` I get the following message:

> whois.domain-registry.nl: Server too busy, try again later

On multiple `.nl` websites. Oddly enough searching for `google.nl` works fine?

---

The `whois` commandline does not get all the information, like `who.is`, and also, it uses the same site to get all the information:

> ```
> > whois example.nl 
> > whois.domain-registry.nl: Server too busy, try again later
> ```

Meaning same error ^

Answer (score 3):

What do you expect the `who.is` website and every other website offering a `whois` mechanism is doing behind the scenes? There'll usually be some caching but they're just using the whois protocol to talk to domain registries. That is to say if you're getting a "Server too busy, try again later" error locally, you'll get it remotely too.

**You're both talking to the same server that's too busy.**

That said, the official registry for a tld *usually* has their own internal whois web service. That is the case for the .nl tld: https://www.sidn.nl/?language_id=2 This is currently accepting queries.

In the case of other domains, Googling for `<tld> registry` usually gets you to somewhere you can "check" to see if a domain is available, and if not, view the registrant details.

Answer (score 0):

Possible the whois commandline tool?

according to the wiki

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS

> Most early web-based WHOIS clients were merely front-ends to a command-line client, where the resulting output just gets displayed on a web page with little, if any, clean-up or formatting.